# CSS dropdown navigation issue

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

http://madeinmayhem.com/ is the site I'm having issues with.

My issue is with the "My Cart" drop down once you've added a product.  I'm having trouble with a list item in one of my dropdowns.

Basically what I need it to do is horizontally list out the information in one row, for a button in the dropdown. In this case it's a product with it's image, name, quantity and cost on one line.  But it's having trouble with the width or something, so the information gets stacked underneath.

I've tried changing everything on it under the sun but can't figure out why it's doing that.  If I change the cart_list ul from position:absolute to relative it expands it fine, but then it messes up the parent link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In future, please post a JSBin.

### EXAMPLE: http://jsbin.com/atELAhat/1/edit?css,output

need to add a width to accommodate the content.

```
/* added */
ul.cart_list > li {width:300px}
```